# How to Get and Install Teradata Client for RHEL platform?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Where I can get Teradata client and install on my RHEL 4/5 machines?

Answer (score 1):

What client are you referring to ? Teradata's [download page](http://www.teradata.com/downloadcenter/) has a list of drivers and access modules - most of which have a Linux version.